# Why is single quote sign escaped inside render element attribute?

Tags: 8

When attribute text contains a single quote, like "It's a nice day" that single quote when rendered is escaped to "It&#039;s a nice day". Why is that happening and can it be prevented? Is twig doing that escaping?

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8.2.x

it says:

"The attribute keys and values are automatically escaped for output with Html::escape()."

and also:

"The attribute values are considered plain text and are treated as such. If a safe HTML string is detected, it is converted to plain text with PlainTextOutput::renderFromHtml() before being escaped."

Neither of those should do that conversion.

Comment: *Why is that happening and can it be prevented? * Because it takes only 2 seconds to see the massive  security issue: `<a class="It's a nice day"...` vs.  `<a class='It's no longer a nice day but a security issue by onclick='evilCode()'...` Do **NOT** prevent that.

Comment: Basically in 99 of 100 cases the answer to *Why is it escaped?* is *Because someone found a security issue* ;-)

Comment: I want a t-shirt with that on @Hudri, great phrase!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes built via the [`Attribute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8.2.x) class are escaped.

The [`Attribute::__toString()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21AttributeValueBase.php/function/AttributeValueBase%3A%3Arender/8.2.x) code is the following one.

```php
$return = '';

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Template\AttributeValueBase $value */
foreach ($this->storage as $name => $value) {
  $rendered = $value->render();
  if ($rendered) {
    $return .= ' ' . $rendered;
  }
}
return $return;
```

In a class that extend `AttributeValueBase`, for example [`AttributeString`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21AttributeString.php/class/AttributeString/8.2.x), [`render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21AttributeValueBase.php/function/AttributeValueBase%3A%3Arender/8.2.x) contains the following code.

```php
value = (string) $this;
if (isset($this->value) && static::RENDER_EMPTY_ATTRIBUTE || !empty($value)) {
  return Html::escape($this->name) . '="' . $value . '"';
}
```

[`AttributeString::__toString()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21AttributeString.php/function/AttributeString%3A%3A__toString/8.2.x) contains the following code.

```php
return Html::escape($this->value);
```

[`Html::escape()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aescape/8.2.x) is called for the attribute name and its value. That's why an attribute built using code similar to the following one single quotes inside the attribute name and value are escaped.

```php
$attributes = new Attribute(array());
$attributes['id'] = 'socks';
$attributes['style'] = 'background-color:white';
echo '<cat ' . $attributes . '>';
```

[`AttributeArray::__toString()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21AttributeArray.php/function/AttributeArray%3A%3A__toString/8.2.x) uses the following code.

```php
// Filter out any empty values before printing.
$this->value = array_unique(array_filter($this->value));
return Html::escape(implode(' ', $this->value));
```

This means that for an attribute built using code similar to the following one, the attribute value is escaped.

```php
$attributes = new Attribute();
$attributes['class'] = array();
$attributes['class'][] = 'cat';
```